# Inheritance on Qt classes with diamond deppendency

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qwidget

I have a Qt application where I put an ImageView on the center of the program. This class inherits from QGraphicsView, and on the top level is the QWidget class. To be more modular, I created another class called ImageViewManager which inherits from ImageView.

This ImageViewManager class should be a QDockWidget on the program, so I can move the dockwidget as I want. That means, this first class inherits also from QDockWidget.

```
class ImageView : public QGraphicsView
{...}

class ImageViewManager : public MyDockWidget, public ImageView
{...}
```

So, in a little class diagram, it is like this:

[image]

At this point, if I want to use, for example, the resize method, it shows an error C2385: ambiguous acces of 'resize'

I did read something about how to solve this method, because this is a diamond problem, but as long as I think I cannot make a virtual inheritance, I'm a bit out of ideas at the moment.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

I tried to make virtual inheritance, and I'm trying to refactor the classes in another way but without taking out functionalities.

Comment: Not every problem in OOP must be solved with inheritance. Remove `ImageViewManager` from the picture and you are left with an `ImageView` that could can add to a `QDockWidget` as a subwidget in a layout. There is no diamond inheritance and looks exactly the same (assuming `ImageView` is the only subwidget of `QDockWidget` and you set all 4 margins of the layout to 0).

Comment: Why would an XYZManager also be an XYZ itself? Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @Atmo I also got that approach, but the problem still there. That means, I cannot resize the widget because it's ambiguous again. MyDockWidget will be ihnerited by ImageView so, AFAIK it's again a diamond problem.

Comment: You have not read my comment correctly. I never said `ImageView` must inherit `QDockWidget` (I wrote `QDockWidget` because your little code sample does not match your diagram but the same applies to `MyDockWidget`). I wrote the opposite: "**Not** every problem in OOP must be solved with inheritance", meaning you should not consider inheritance to solve this case and "add an `ImageView` [*instance*] to a `QDockWidget` [*instance*] as **a subwidget in a layout**", not as a class in an inheritance tree.